# Interior $C^1$ estimate for quasilinear elliptic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, elliptic-equations

This is taken from Qin Han's book Nonlinear elliptic equations of the second order.

(Theorem 2.2.1) Let $a_{ij} \in C^1(B_R \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfy the uniform ellipticity and for any $x \in B_R$ and $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there are some positive constants $A_0,A_1$ such that
$$R | \nabla_x a_{ij}(x,p)| \leq A_0, \qquad |p| |\nabla_p a_{ij}(x,p)| \leq A_1 $$
Suppose $u \in L^\infty(B_R) \cap C^3(B_R)$ is a solution of
$$a_{ij}(x,\nabla u(x)) = f(x) \quad \text{ in } B_R $$
for some $f \in C^1(B_R)$ with $|f|_{C^1(B_R)} < \infty$
Then
$$R |\nabla u|_{L^\infty(B_{R/2})} \leq C (|u|_{L^\infty(B_R)} + R^2 |f|_{L^\infty(B_R)} + R^3 |\nabla f|_{L^\infty(B_R)})  $$

I understand the proof except the last part. He proves that
$$\sup_{B_R} (\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2 + \frac{c_1}{\lambda R^2} u^2 ) \leq C \sup_{B_R} (\frac{u^2}{R^2} + R^2 f^2 +R^4 |\nabla f|^2) $$

where $\eta \in C_0^2(B_R)$ is a cut off function with $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$, $\eta = 1$ in $B_{R/2}$  and
$$ |\nabla \eta|^2+|\nabla^2 \eta| \leq c_0$$
and $\lambda$ is the constant lower bound of the uniform ellipticity.

I dont understand how that estimate implies the first one, I managed to prove that
$$|\nabla u|_{L^\infty(B_{R/2})}^2 \leq C(\frac{|u|_{L^\infty(B_R)}^2}{R^2} + R^2 |f^2|_{L^\infty(B_R)} + R^4 |\nabla f|^2_{L^\infty(B_R)})  $$
but I dont see how that implies the desired estimate. Any help appreciated

Pd: Han defines the $L^\infty$ norm as $|u|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} = \sup_{\Omega} |u|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the square root on both sides and then multiply both sides by $R$. Then on the right hand side use the inequality

$$\sqrt{a+b+c} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c},$$

for nonnegative numbers $a,b,c$ (to see this, just square both sides).